# Making Django work with Apache

Tags: python, django, apache, networking, model-view-controller

I have a test django project that I have been using the django development server for. I want to start using an actual apache server to properly simulate a production environment. I am using Mac OS X.

I have been using [this tutorial here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/modwsgi/), but in the first set of instructions I am getting a 403 from localhost. The browser says I do not have permission to access `/` on the server.

When I comment out the apache config line from the tutorial, `WSGIScriptAlias / /Users/username/Projects/django_books/django_books/django.wsgi` I can access localhost.

This is the contents of my django.wsgi file:

```
import os
import sys

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'django_books.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

path = '/Users/username/Projects/django_books/django_books'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
```

What is causing the 403 and why can't I see my django application?

### EDIT

Directory structure:

```
django_books
    apache (empty directory right now)
    random_book
        __init__.py
        models.py
        views.py
    django_books
        __init__.py
        django.wsgi
        settings.py
        urls.py
        views.py
        wsgi.py
    media
    static
        css
            style.css
    manage.py
```

### 2ND EDIT

Permissions on all the directories:

/Users/username/Projects/django_books/django_books/django.wsgi

```
-rw-r--r--
```

/Users/username/Projects/django_books/django_books

```
drwxr-xr-x
```

/Users/username/Projects/django_books/

```
drwxr-xr-x
```

/Users/username/Projects/

```
drwxr-xr-x
```

/Users/username/

```
drwxr-xr-x+
```

/Users/

```
drwxr-xr-x
```

Answer (score 1):

According to my small experience I think you must add the following lines "just below the import sys line to place your project on the path" (so juste under "import sys") like it's said in the tutorial you quote. Also, erase the second "django_books" in your path because you want to link to your site not the app in your site ;-) ("mysite" in the tutorial, not mysite/mysite)

```
import os
import sys

path = '/Users/username/Projects/django_books'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'django_books.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Bye

Comment: I'm confused. The code in your answer is the same as mine; what lines should I be adding? And the first django_books folder is just a container folder created by virtualevnwrapper. The second django_books is actually my project, with all the apps in the same directory as it.

Comment: So you have 3 folder django_books ? /Users/username/Projects/django_books/django_book/django_book/ exist ? 
I have edited my answer to show properly the code and the order of the differents parts.

Comment: The difference is that @HydrUra adds to sys.path before creating the WSGIHandler I guess.

Comment: Ok for your edit. Before that you're in "Projects" ? In that case, you have to :
move django.wsgi in the first folder django_books, 
use my code exactly as I posted it,
also change the path to your django.wsgi in apache.
Restart apache and it will work !

Comment: @jefffabiny Did you try to move your django.wsgi and paste the code I have written ? It will works...

Answer (score 1):

It's likely an issue related either to your Apache installation, python library, or the filesystem's permissions.

### Testing Apache

You don't say it in your question, but I assume from your link you are working with Apache2 and [mod_wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/).

You can test if Apache and mod_wsgi (or your wsgi module) are working properly by placing a dummy wsgi script in the place of django.wsgi . This script (stolen from [mod_wsgi's docs](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/)) doesn't rely on Django and helps make sure that Apache can read and execute the wsgi script:

```
# test version of django.wsgi
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                    ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

And restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Go ahead and test the page. Did it work? Great. Undo the changes to the django.wsgi script, restart Apache and test again. If the Django site still doesn't work, we need to keep looking. If the test script didn't work, there may be a problem with your Apache installation. Check apache's error log for more information about what happened. On linux it's commonly at `/var/log/apache2/error.log` . `mod_wsgi` could be improperly installed, the script's daemon may not have appropriate permission to the wsgi file.

### Correcting permission errors

Apache may not be able to read and execute the wsgi file. Running `ls -l` in the wsgi file's directory as indicated in other answers will tell you the user and group a file belongs to (and if that user and group can read, write, or execute a given file). It's common for a default installation to have the wsgi permissions like so:

```
-rw------- 1 www-data www-data 1470 Aug 29 16:00 django.wsgi
```

If you want to use a different user for the daemon process, you need to make sure that the apache conf file defines `WSGIDaemonProccess`

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /Users/username/Projects/django_books/django_books/django.wsgi
WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi_user processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIProcessGroup wsgi_group
```

Testing changes to these files and restarting Apache can help narrow down what's up. Keep checking the Apache log files.

### Apache Configuration

Django's tutorial on setting up mod_wsgi is good, but read through mod_wsgi's wiki as well. There are a lot of helpful things to consider in your apache conf file besides `WSGIScriptAlias`. Make sure there is a  tag pointing to the folder with your wsgi file. If there are non-public files (like django project files) in that directory, either use the apache directory (update your apache conf file) or add a  tag under the  node to keep those other files private. While you're in there, you may notice other things that look wrong, like an improperly configured servername, multiple virtual hosts, or other errors.

### Testing Python

If you're using virtualenv ([do it](http://www.clemesha.org/blog/modern-python-hacker-tools-virtualenv-fabric-pip/)), make sure that
 1. The `WSGIDaemonProcess` variable defines the appropriate site-packages and the wsgi script's location in the variable's python-path attribute
 2. The daemon has rights to read the site packages in your virtualenv.
 3. Your wsgi script properly imports django and your site's settings.

### Logging Apache

You can increase the level of logging reported by Apache by adding a few lines to your Apache conf file. This setup gives you very verbose logging that you may want during deployment (make sure to make a log folder):

```
LogLevel info
ErrorLog /Users/username/Projects/django_books/logs/apache_error.log
CustomLog /Users/username/Projects/django_books/logs/apache_access.log combined
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough response. Can you please see the edit to my question regarding permissions?

Comment: The permission information in the 2nd Edit is only helpful you know who is given those permissions. `ls -l` outputs a table without headers. If you were to add those headers, they would be "file type & permissions" "# of hard links" "owner name" "group name" "size in bytes" "timestamp of modification" "filename". In other words, the permissions in the 2nd edit don't help without knowing the owner name and group name (what was in the 3rd and 4th column of `ls -l` output).

`django.wsgi` is the file that is most likely to have incorrect permissions.

Comment: The 'other' permissions should be sufficient to give access to the file?

Comment: @DouglasLeeder I agree. I prefer specifying the daemon as the owner of of the file, but modifying the `other` permissions is far more straightforward and simple.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that the www-data (or whatever user apache is running as) doesn't have access to `/Users/username/Projects/django_books/django_books`.

`su` to that user and try and access that directory and the wsgi file within it.

To print all the relevant permissions:

`ls -ld /Users /Users/username /Users/username/Projects /Users/username/Projects/django_books /Users/username/Projects/django_books/django_books /Users/username/Projects/django_books/django_books/django.wsgi`

You should also check the apache error logs, they might tell you what is going wrong.

Comment: These are the permissions for the 2nd django_books directory: drwxr-xr-x and the permissions for the file are: -rw-r--r--

Comment: @jefffabiny Have you checked you can access the directory as the web user? That user will need execute permissions to all the parent directories as well.

Comment: `ls -l / /Users /Users/username /Users/username/Projects /Users/username/Projects/django_books /Users/username/Projects/django_books/django_books /Users/username/Projects/django_books/django_books/django.wsgi`

Comment: I just edited my question to include the permissions for all these.

Comment: @jefffabiny I'd go with the things Mr. Dave suggests then.